# Одна переменная для 4 чисел

Tags: python, if, переменные

Питон. Если среди чисел отрицательные? для решения задания нужно использовать только одну переменную (а). Чисел всего должно быть 4. И потом вывести ответ: правда или ложь. Нельзя использовать массив и другие циклы (кроме if)

Comment: if (a==первое_число or a==второе_число or...)

Comment: перефразируйте вопрос, а то непонятно что именно нужно

Comment: А что с этими числами потом должно происходить ? Переменная, не массив может одновременно содержать только одно значение. Это конечно может быть и строка например с числами через запятую, но что бы с ним работать все равно  в массив превращать надо. И очень может быть, что решение в "одновременно не может", может быть читать в переменную числа по очереди и обрабатывать ? Короче опишите проблему более подробно

Comment: задача звучит так: есть  или среди чисел отрицательнве? но нам сказали для этой задачи использовать только 1 переменную. и в ответе нужно написать правда это или ложь

Comment: Значит все верно, никакого "одновременно" вам не нужно. Надо сделать цикл, внутри которого вы получается input() очередное значение переменной и тут же проверяете ее на меньше нуля. А дальше в зависимости от желаемого результата либо запоминаете на будущее (в другой переменной) факт что встречали отрицательное, либо сразу же сообщаете об этом. Конечно надо решить на чем заканчивать этот цикл. Его можно сделать например пока не введут 0, или пока не введут определенное количество чисел, ну или вообще только до первого отрицательного и после сразу завершаться

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А вот про эту фразу подробнее: '_Нельзя использовать массив и другие циклы_' цикл и массив это совершенно разные вещи. Точно есть запрет на использование цикла ?

Comment: да, массив сказали использовать нельзя, и нельзя использовать циклы кроме if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[НОВЬЕ]**

раз автор добавил дополнительное условие:

> Нельзя использовать массив и другие циклы (кроме if)

```
res = int(input('Введите число #1: ')) > 0
res &= int(input('Введите число #2: ')) > 0
res &= int(input('Введите число #3: ')) > 0
res &= int(input('Введите число #4: ')) > 0
print('ПРАВДА' if res else 'ЛОЖЬ')
```

впрочем тут в явном виде даже `if` не используется :)

**[СТАРЬЕ]**

можно так:

```
data = list(map(int, input('Введите числа через пробел: ').split()))

print('Все числа положительные' if all(i > 0 for i in data) else 'Не все числа положительные')
```

правда в задаче информация про ввод именно 4 чисел, тогда можно так:

```
data = []
for i in range(4):
    data.append(int(input(f'Введите число №{i}')))

print('Все числа положительные' if all(i > 0 for i in data) else 'Не все числа положительные')
```

Comment: что значит data?

Comment: ничего - переменную так назвал для удобства, но поскольку вы добавили условие, что списки нельзя использовать, то в свой ответ добавил код без каких либо списков и циклов

Comment: в новом варианте описание к input нужно поправить, чтобы цифры совпадали)

Comment: а можно также как, но и иф?

Comment: можно, вместо `(a > 0)` можно записать `True if a > 0 else False` - смысл тот же, то такая запись совершенно ненужная, приведенный код использует булеву логику и делает логический `AND` ко всем 4 сравнениям с числами и `True`  будет только в том случае, когда все 4 сравнения выдали `True`. По идее задачу вообще в 1 строчку можно было бы записать `res = int(input()) > 0 and int(input()) > 0 and int(input()) > 0 and int(input()) > 0` - тоже никаких `if`, только при выводе результата, и там можно без `if`, но тогда нужен список :) `('ЛОЖЬ', 'ПРАВДА')[res]`

Comment: да, конечно можно по разному сократить и написать эту программу, но просто препод по другому не зачтет

Comment: Странный препод :), а такое устроит `if int(input()) > 0 and int(input()) > 0 and int(input()) > 0 and int(input()) > 0: print('ПРАВДА') else: print('ЛОЖЬ')` - все условия соблюдены. А вообще раз это обучающая задача... попробуйте разные способы. Честно говоря не совсем понятно, что именно преподу нужно. Можно индийский код написать с кучей `if`, который также будет правильно работать, но будет очень неэффективным